# naming new objects from a string array

Tags: java

very new to java and trying to get a project done for school so any help would be appreciated! I am trying to make new objects of a class and naming them using strings from an array. I know this is an odd way of doing it but to get certain marks you have to show your program is expandable in this way.....sooooo
Particle is another class

```
public class test1v1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] iValue = { 1, 2, 0 };
    double[] jValue = { 1, 2, 0 };
    String[] name = { "earth", "moon", "sun" };

    Particle [name[1]] = new Particle(iValue[1],jValue[1]);
```

So I would like to do a loop and make three new objects called earth, moon and sun. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest using a `Map<Particle>` for this. (`Map<String, Particle>` rather)

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: @CollinD A `Map<String, Particle>`, you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you'd like here, but you can create a `Map` to achieve a similar effect.

```
double[] iValue = { 1, 2, 0 };
double[] jValue = { 1, 2, 0 };
String[] name = { "earth", "moon", "sun" };
Map<String, Particle> heavenlyBodies = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    heavenlyBodies.put(name[i], new Particle(iValue[i], jValue[i]));
}
```

These particles can then be retrieved in the following manner if so desired

```
Particle earth = heavenlyBodies.get("earth");
```

See the docs for `Map<K, V>`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to CollinD's answer, the issue here is you cannot take a literal value, (e.g. "earth", "moon", and "sun") which is stored in your program's compiled code to be used at runtime for the purpose of your program, as the names of variables which are simply keywords in your source code which give a meaningful name to the variable to make it easier to understand your code.

The use of a map is allowing you to create a way of storing named variables at runtime.